# Node.js endpoint with knex does not return anything. Front-end stucks without reply

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, knex.js

I am using Knex in my Node.js code for an endpoint:

```
app.post('/admin/west/savings', async(req, res) => {
   await knex('savingswest').insert(req.body.savingsData).onConflict('dt').merge()

  return 'okay'

})
```

The endpoint is called like this in my front-end (React.js):

```
 axios
        .post(`${address}/admin/west/savings`, {
          savingsData: newArr, //THE DATA I SEND TO THE ENDPOINT
        })
        .then((response) => {
          setLoading(false);
          setResults(response.data);
          console.log(response.data);
          return response.data;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
          setLoading(false);
        });
    }
```

**Everything in database is saved correct** but the front-end endpoint stucks here - I do not get any feedback from the back-end. Even if I make axios call in async function still nothing. Could anyone figure it out why front-end is not receiving anything?

Comment: In node.js. use
 return res.status(200).send('okay)

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure the issue is that you need to use your res object on your post request.

```js
app.post('/admin/west/savings', async(req, res) => {
   await knex('savingswest').insert(req.body.savingsData).onConflict('dt').merge()

  res.status(200).json({res.data})

})
```

However I would highly encourage you to write your .then().catch() statement on the backend so you can throw the appropriate response type for different scenarios. for example.

Something along the lines of this:

```js
app
  .post("/admin/west/savings", async (req, res) => {
    knex("savingswest").insert(req.body.savingsData).onConflict("dt").merge();
  })
  .then((response) => {
    res.status(200).json({ response });
  })
  .catch((err) => res.status(500).json({ message: err.message }));
```

Hope that helps and let me know if you have any questions!